# Why won't my Ender 5 Pro move back to its home and won't print after firmware update?

Tags: firmware, creality-ender-5

I just updated the firmware of my Ender 5 Pro to `Ender-5 ProMarlin2.0.6HW4.2.2GDBLTouchFilament`. Since then my printer won't return to its correct home.

When it starts printing, it moves to the middle but drops the build plate about 4 cm then extrudes a little bit of filament, then the build plate and extruder start to cool down, and the progress bar continues going up despite everything else being at a halt.

Comment: Do you have a filament sensor to detect broken filament?

Comment: No, I don't, no auto levelling either but I've noticed it's an option to pick on the printer so I'm wondering if I picked the wrong firmware..

Comment: Then this is the incorrect firmware! Hence it doesn't work. I'll try to answer your question later.